# Feeding guides help Kirkland for cats

Tags: cats, diet

My cat weights 10 pounds. I am reading the feeding guides and it says that a cat of that weight should eat 1/2 - 2/3 cups per day. I do not have a scale, but I do have a vase with millilitre marks on it. How many millilitres should I give him per day? A quick conversion would say 236.5 millilitres. However the guideline also says: 4008 kcal/kg (443 kcal/cup), which yields 110 grams per cup. I have found on the internet that "A 44 pound bag of dog food would contain 176 cups of dog food in each bag". Is there any Kirkland user that could corroborate that 236.5 millilitres of Kirkland food matches the 110 grams? Thanks!!

Here is the feeding guideline:

[image]

Comment: Assuming a [US cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_(unit)) of 240 ml, ½ cup would be 120 ml, and ⅔ cup 160 ml. I don't know this specific brand of food, but 110 grams seems a bit too much, our cats get ~40 grams of dry food per day.

Comment: @Berend do you know what is the volume of the 40 grams you give your cats?

Comment: It's kind of hard to measure precisely, but my best guess would be 120–130 ml. This would be in line with ½ cup.

Comment: Aside the question there is another problem with this guidline: cats with big weight gets more food than cats with less weight. If ones cat has overweight this measure guideline will intensify the effect... so one need to use ones mind anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to just use a kitchen scale, good for making bread and coffee too. Just weigh the empty container, tare it and weigh the new food. 
Let's say that's not an option for you. Because foods are measured by weight and not by volume and you want volume. I can show you there's some things that you can do

1)you need 176 cups/44lbs of dog food, will only yield the conversion ratio for that dog food with that kibble size.

2) Without knowing the volume of the vase or it's shape that's impossible to determine any correlation there.

3) A kg appears to be little over a cup, so, you could take (333kcal/1c.)x(1 kg/3564kcal)= ( .09343kg/c.)= 93.43g/c.

4) Then take (93.4g/c.)(1c./2)=46.717g or 93.4x(3/4)=70.07g etc.